# ubuntu document reader for acrobat pdf forms

Tags: ubuntu, pdf

I have an acrobat pdf form that I need to fill. I am using ubuntu 14.04 trusty. Is there a reader that can handle this, the default (evince) doesn't seem to work.

thanks

Comment: Is it filling out for purposes of printing out, for saving and passing on, or for online submission to a server? (In order of increasing difficulty.)

Comment: I need to fill it out, but currently can't even view it!